# Como puedo obtener los datos del siguiente json en java?

Tags: java, json

Verán, tengo el siguiente json:

```
"signaturesType":[
            "SIMPLE"
         ],
         "docs":[
            "contrato"
         ]
```

Como puedo obtener los valores dentro de los tags signaturesType y docs.
Lo que me cabe de extraño es que no viene como el clásico json, que sería propiedad : valor, es por eso de mi duda de como puedo obtener los valores ahí alojados.
Saludos y gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes utilizar [Google Gson](https://github.com/google/gson), pero primero tendrías que modificar tu json ya que le hacen falta las llaves **{ }** para indicar que lo que esta dentro es un objeto, puedes checar todo eso aquí [JSON org](https://www.json.org/json-es.html), los corchetes **[ ]** en JSON representan un array y pueden mapearse a un **Collection**  como un  **List** o un **Array**.

```
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {

        String json = "{'signaturesType':["+
                          "'SIMPLE'"+
                       "],"+
                       "'docs':["+
                          "'contrato'"+
                       "]}";

        // Aquí se hace la conversión
        Data data = new Gson().fromJson(json, Data.class);

        // Se muestra así
        System.out.println(data.getSignaturesType().get(0));

        // Se muestra así
        System.out.println(data.getDocs().get(0));
    }

}

class Data {
    private List<String> signaturesType;
    private List<String> docs;
    /**
     * @return the signaturesType
     */
    public List<String> getSignaturesType() {
        return signaturesType;
    }
    /**
     * @param signaturesType the signaturesType to set
     */
    public void setSignaturesType(List<String> signaturesType) {
        this.signaturesType = signaturesType;
    }
    /**
     * @return the docs
     */
    public List<String> getDocs() {
        return docs;
    }
    /**
     * @param docs the docs to set
     */
    public void setDocs(List<String> docs) {
        this.docs = docs;
    }
}
```

Este sería el resultado:

SIMPLE

contrato

Answer (score -1):

Para estar bien formado el objecto json debería ser:

```
{"signaturesType":["SIMPLE"],"docs":["contrato"]}
```

Lo que equivale a una clase java

```
public class Xxx{
    public List<String> signaturesType;
    public List<String> docs;
}
```

Usando la libreria [gson](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5) podés convertir el String en una instancia de una clase java.

```
String jsonString = "{\"signaturesType\":[\"SIMPLE\"],\"docs\":[\"contrato\"]}";
Xxx xxx = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, Xxx.class);
```

Comment: Cuidado con las comillas en el código

Comment: @Niche Gracias. Ahí lo corregí para el ejemplo